# Android Array to ListView: NullExceptionPointer

Tags: android, arrays, listview, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android and I am trying to display the arrays on a listview, but I'm getting a nullpointerexception with these codes. I tried displaying my array with a toast, and I think there's no problem with it. Is there something wrong with how I declared the ArrayAdapter? Here are my codes:

```
ListView lvnames;
ArrayList<String> arrnames = new ArrayList<String>();

    String [] name = new String [3];

    name [0] = "a";
    name [1] = "b";
    name [2] = "c";


    for (String complete : name){
        arrnames.add(complete);
    }

    lvnames.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrnames));
    lvnames.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

PS: I've tried 
ListAdapter la1 = new ArrayAdapter [and] ArrayAdapter la1 = new ArrayAdapter , but none of these works.

Comment: Please post your stacktrace, but I do not see `lvnames` being initialized anywhere.

Comment: Probably `lvnames` is `null`

Comment: @Emmanuel : do you mean this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alphatest/com.example/alphatest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: have you declared lvnames=(ListView)findviewbyid(R.id.listview);